# Spring Security - Ownership based access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

Let's say I've a minimal RESTful controller like the following, by the way using Java 8 and Spring Boot 2, ...

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService service;    

    @GetMapping
    public Post get() {

        return service.getLatest();
    }
}
```

I've secured this route successfully using the Spring Security module. Now I want to allow only the resource owner access to this resource. With resource owner I mean the creator or saying it simple:

```
Post myPost = new Post();
...
myPost.getCreator().equals(currentUser); // Should be true when access is granted
```

I found a lot about role based access, but nearly nothing for checking ownership... Of course I could place an if statement inside of the controller and throw an exception, but I intended to use something like Spring's *Expression-Based Access Control*.

Any other ideas? Does somebody have a good idea or example for ownership checking of a resource?

Comment: I *think* (but I'm not certain), *"owner based access"* is called *"Discretionary Access Control"* because the owner always has access, and the owner decides who else may access the resource. Contrast this to *"Mandatory Access Control"*, where system policies determine who has access to the resource. In a Mandatory Access Controls system, the owner/creator of a resource may not have access to the resource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a simple get operation you can just return the post linked to your current logged in user

```
@GetMapping
public Post getPost(Authentication authentication) {
    return service.getPostByUser(authentication.getName());
}
```

For updating an existing post, you can check within the PreAuthorize if the creator is the logged in user. authentication.getName() gives back an email in my example

```
@PutMapping
@PreAuthorize("#post.getCreator() == authentication.getName()")
public void update(@RequestBody Post post, Authentication authentication) {
    service.updatePost(post);
}
```

Basic example of the @Component way

```
@Autowired
private CreatorCheck creatorCheck;

@PutMapping
@PreAuthorize("@creatorChecker.check(#post,authentication)")
public void update(@RequestBody Post post, Authentication authentication) {
    service.updatePost(post);
}
```

And the component.. Can be extended to retrieve the original Post and check that creator..

```
@Component
public class CreatorCheck {

    public boolean check(Post post, Authentication authentication) {
       return post.getCreator().equals(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

For a more comprehensive tutorial check out this [tutorial](https://lyubomyr-shaydariv.github.io/posts/2016-08-07-spring-security-preauthorize-annotation-custom-types-and-inspectable-dsl-support/) link found by [0x1C1B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9107502/0x1c1b)

Comment: But this means the client is setting the post's creator inside the request right? How can I prevent that it manipulates the creator? Let's say using it's own id to grant access... Or for an DELETE request, theres no DTO/payload given as argument...

Comment: You could write another @Component public CreatorChecker class to handle the checks. 

@PreAuthorize("@creatorChecker.check(#post,authentication)")

In this component you retrieve the post from the DB and check the creator  service.getPostId().getCreator() == authentication.getName() like that

Comment: Where is this component used? As part of the filter chain? Is this a common aproach I found nothing like this... But seems to be an interessting solution

Comment: It will get evaluated the same way as some default stuff such as hasRole('FOO') as it just a different expression that needs to evaluated.

[Spring Docs Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.html)

Comment: That's my favorite solution... I found a basic [example](https://lyubomyr-shaydariv.github.io/posts/2016-08-07-spring-security-preauthorize-annotation-custom-types-and-inspectable-dsl-support/) about using external components for authorization. Could you update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Added a basic example for your specific use case and linked the tutorial you found.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) is a small guide that helped me solve this problem. 
If you use the CRUD Repository:

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("#entity.id == authentication.principal.id")
<S extends User> S save(S entity);
```

For resource owner and admin:

```
@PreAuthorize("#entity.id == authentication.principal.id || hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
```

so, just override the required method in your child CRUD Repository. It works and for `@RepositoryRestResource`

Answer (score 0):

In a role based approach, roles are predefined irrespective of the response/resource. But in your case we need to get the resource first to check whether the user is the owner or not. We can't decide before hand.

Let say, if user has a ROLE_ADMIN, he will be admin for all the resources.
In your case the ownership is dependent purely on resources. I advise you to go with manual `if` check. In case the `Post` Object is heavy you can maintain a separate table with just two columns resource_id and owner. then if owner matches you can fetch the resource later otherwise you can send 403 forbidden response to the user.

Comment: Yea as I already mentioned I tried this, but for many routes and different resources you have to write a lot of boilerplate code...